# error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'push'

Tags: c, struct, compiler-errors, linked-list, singly-linked-list

I'm tryng to build a linked list, but i can't pass the errors. Somebody can help me undertand what is going on? I already change the type of the structures, but nothing changes.

I'm tryng to build a linked list, but i can't pass the errors. Somebody can help me undertand what is going on? I already change the type of the structures, but nothing changes.

```
/*gcc -o lista.exe lista.c -Wall -pedantic -Wextra*/
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

struct list
{
  int info;
  struct list *next;
};

void push(struct list, int);

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
  struct list *list;

  argc = argc;
  argv = argv;

  /*Start list*/
  list = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  list->info = 5;
  list->next = NULL;

  push(&list, 70);

  return 0;
}

void push(struct list **list, int info)
{
  struct list *new;
  new = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));
  new->info = info;
  new->next = NULL;

  *list->next = new;
}
```

```
lista.c: In function 'main':
lista.c:25:3: error: incompatible type for argument 1 of 'push'
lista.c:11:6: note: expected 'struct list' but argument is of type 'struct list **'
lista.c: At top level:
lista.c:30:6: error: conflicting types for 'push'
lista.c:11:6: note: previous declaration of 'push' was here
lista.c: In function 'push':
lista.c:37:8: error: request for member 'next' in something not a structure or union
```

Comment: @eanpdt What thsi magic statements    argc = argc;
  argv = argv; do?

Comment: @eanpdt Just substitute the parameters of main for void.

Comment: OT: regarding: `list = (struct list *)malloc(sizeof(struct list));`  1) In C, the returned type is `void*` which can be assigned to any pointer.  Casting just clutters the code.  Suggest removing that cast.  2) when calling `malloc()`, always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful, call `perror( "malloc failed" );` followed by: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: regarding: `struct list *list;`  it is a poor programming practice to use the name of a type as a variable name.  Suggest: `struct list *myList;`

Comment: regarding: `void push(struct list **list, int info)`  Why the `**`?  the code is not going to change where the `list` variable is going to point

Comment: @VladfromMoscow i suppose it is an attempt to dismiss compiler warnings about unused variable

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your function prototype/declaration for `push` doesn't match your function definition for `push`.  At the top, change

```
void push(struct list, int);
```

to

```
void push(struct list**, int);
```

Alternatively, you could erase the function prototype for `push` and move the definition for it above `main`.  The compiler reads files top to bottom, and so in `main` when you call `push(&list, 70);`, the compiler will complain if it doesn't know of a function matching that signature.  Since your prototype is wrong, it doesn't see a function matching a return type of `void` with arguments `struct list**, int`, so it generates the error that you see.

An aside, I assume you have

```
argc = argc;
argv = argv;
```

to suppress warnings from unused variables.  If you don't plan to use `argc` or `argv`, you can change your `main` signature to `int main(void){ ... }` and dispose of them entirely.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler sees the declaration

```
void push(struct list, int);
```

after that it encounters this call

```
push(&list, 70);
```

where the first argument has the type `struct list **`. And it issues an error that type of the function parameter `struct list` and the type of the argument expression `struct list **` are not compatible.

The function declaration without definition does not coincide with the function declaration with definition after the function main.

But in any case the function definition is invalid.

This statement within the function

```
*list->next = new;
```

is incorrect. It is equivalent to

```
*( list->next ) = new;
```

where the pointer `list` having the type `struct list **` points to a pointer not to a structure object. That is the pointed pointer does not have the data member `next`. And the compiler reports about this

> lista.c:37:8: error: request for member 'next' in something not a
>   structure or union

The function should be declared the following way

```
int push( struct list **, int );
```

and defined like

```
int push( struct list **list, int info )
{
    struct list *new_node = malloc( sizeof( struct list ) );
    int success = new_node != NULL;

    if ( success )
    {
        new_node->info = info;
        new_node->next = *list;
        *list = new_node;
    }

    return success;
}
```

And in main there is no need to allocate the head node outside the function `push`.

You should write

```
int main( void )
{
    struct list *list = NULL;

    push( &list, 5 );
    push( &list, 70 );

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: this answer was quite good, until: `*list = new_node;`  Which will change where the head node in `main()` points.  However, that `head node` already points to an allocation of memory so this statement results in a memory leak and DOES NOT result in two entries in the linked list

Comment: what is this: `int success new_node != NULL;` expected to do?  Perhaps you meant: `if( ! new_node ) { // handle error }`

Comment: @user3629249 On-sided singly-linked list append new nodes to the beginning of a list. There is no memory leak. See the implementation of main I showed. So your comment does not make sense.

Comment: @user3629249 The function implementation is very simple and clear. I wonder that you are asking such a question. This statement assigns a flag whether a memory was allocated successfully. What is unclear?!

Comment: That may be the OP wants to insert the new node at the beginning of the list, however; that is not what is being done.  This statement, from the OPs code, `*list->next = new;` says the OP is trying to append the new node, not insert before the existing node(s)

Comment: @user3629249 He just does not know lists very well because he is a beginner. He can exchange the calls of push to push the numbers in what order he wants.

Comment: this statement: `int success new_node != NULL;` is NOT assigning anything to `success`.  Perhaps you meant: `int success = (new_node != NULL);`

Comment: @user3629249 There was a typo. I updated the declaration.